# Inputting into a char* declared earlier crashes the program while doing that into a 'just-declared' char* doesn't. Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

This code crashes the program

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    char *name1;
    char *name2 = "Mark";
    gets(name1);
    puts(name1);
    return 0;
}
```

whereas this doesn't

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    char *name1 = "Mark";
    char *name2;
    gets(name2);
    puts(name2);
    return 0;
}
```

Why ?
I am using MinGW with Code::Blocks IDE.

Comment: Don' use naked pointers. Use `std::string`. Naked pointers are terrifyingly hard to understand and use correctly.

Comment: both versions are wrong: there is no space reserved/allocated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just lucky that one crashes and other doesn't.
Both of the programs produce undefined behavior.

```
char *name2;
gets(name2);
```

You need to point the pointer to a valid and big enough memory to be able to write to it. You are just writing to a uninitialized pointer. This results in Undefined behavior. **Undefined behavior does not mandate a crash, it literally means any behavior is possible**, as in your case it might crash sometimes and may not but nevertheless it is a incorrect program.

Ideal Solution is to simply use `std::string`.
If you insist on using `char *` you need to point this pointer to a valid memory. For e.g.

```
char myArr[256];
char *name2 = &myArr;
```

Comment: "and big enough memory" -- Just how do you propose to make sure that there is enough memory to store the input that `gets` reads? :)

Comment: @Alok A Good and Quick Answer. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

Both are Undefined Behavior, will it crash or not, is rather matter of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the memory for your input, but you don't. If you want to stick at *gets* and *puts* you should change `char *name` to `char name[100]` or allocate memory:

```
char *name = new char[100];
...
delete name;
```

If you need more than 100 chars (including the \0 char at the end of the string) you have to increase the size accordingly.

In C++ using `std::string` is most likely the better alternative.